# AngularJS UI lags on socket receive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

My code is the following:

```
var vm = this;
vm.debugMessages = [];
socket.on("message", function (data) {

  $scope.$apply(function (err) {

    vm.message.push(data);
  });
});
```

Every time I get a message over the socket, it pushes the new data to an array. The array is shown in a template as a table. Unfortunately, the UI lags everytime new data arrives. Futhermore it takes time before the new content of the array is shown in the view. What can I do?

EDIT: There are up to five messages per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had same issue and found a solution that works for me. Instead use the scope try to deal with rootScope and add a little protection to prevent angular digest error. 
In socket.io message event, first push data to array and call rootScope apply method. You can try with something like this : if ($rootScope.$$phase != '$apply' && $rootScope.$$phase != '$digest') $rootScope.$apply();

Dont forget to inject $rootScope dependency.